# Как открыть/редактировать палитру рисунка BMP?

Tags: python-3.x, графика

http://www.nestego.ru/2012/07/blog-post_31.html

Не смог найти как открыть палитру и переопределить цвета, не знает ли кто?

Comment: Что значит "открыть палитру", что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Указал ведь статью) Нужно переприсвоить 26 цветов палитры черного цвета, т.к. я хочу по образу и подобию вшить в картинку текст из английских букв (a=0,b=1...z=26)  я уже месяц бьюсь не могу найти как с этой проклятой палитрой работать из питона, не говоря уже о решение моей зАДачи

Comment: и не найдете, палитра есть только у 8(и меньше) битных рисунков BMP =) а так же например у GIF рисунков =) и стенография так не делается=))

Comment: http://www.nestego.ru/2012/07/blog-post_31.html  не верите сами посмотрите статью, похожую находил на английском так что не знаю как она по другому делается - просвятите буду рад, т.к. с методом замены бит (LBS) меня отправили и "тыкнули в палитру лицом" :)

Comment: Вперед за теорией https://habr.com/post/422593/ еще чуть чуть по теме https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP , и это только начало, дальше - больше!!

Comment: Это уже было изучено вдоль и поперек но, повторюсь, все это треклятый LSB стеганография а мне наказали сделать именно "метод замены цветовой палитры" распроложенный на страничке 36 - красивые слова а на деле - кукишъ =)  https://www.bsuir.by/m/12_100229_1_69111.pdf

Comment: Так а зачем дело стало? я вам скинул ссыль на вики, с полным описанием формата BMP =) читайте =)

Comment: Блок BITMAPINFO состоит из трёх частей:

 - Структура с информационными полями.
 - Битовые маски для извлечения значений цветовых каналов (присутствуют не всегда).
 - `Таблица цветов (присутствует не всегда)`

Comment: В битностях 8 и ниже цвет пикселя указывается индексом в таблице цветов, в высших: непосредственным значением в цветовой модели RGB. Альфа-канал опционально может быть добавлен в битностях 16 и 32. В битности 64 он присутствует перманентно.

Comment: Это все тоже самое вики, так что читайте и пилите =)